# dnsmasq resolver on different port

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

Im trying to use dnsmasq in conjunction with dnscrypt. I can't get dnsmasq to work with a server being a local address / non dns port. Is this possible?
I've tried setting dnscrypt to

- 127.0.0.1
- 192.168.1.15
- 127.0.0.2

None worked, tried setting dnscrypt to 127.0.0.1:52, but dnsmasq wont allow a server to run on a different port to 53???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run DNSCrypt as a forwarder for a local DNS cache (recommended), use `dnscrypt-proxy`.

`dnscrypt-proxy` can be configured to listen on a different port than 53, since port 53 is reserved your the DNS cache software (`dnsmasq`).

[This link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DNSCrypt#DNSCrypt_as_a_forwarder_for_local_DNS_cache) includes a configuration example for `dnsmasq`.

More information (and a link to PPA) is available here: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-ubuntu-with.html

Comment: yep but what I want to do is have the dnsmasq reslover address on a different port, not the listening address

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying and editing your question. See my updated answer.

Comment: awesome, just needed to use # rather than : in dnsmasq.

Comment: Glad it worked!